# Disposal pipe level or slightly below stub out

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, disposal

Disposal drain is level or slightly below stub out. Will this cause a problem for the p trap connection and allow for proper drain? Farmhouse sink going in so the disposal will now hang lower. Thanks

Comment: how much is "slightly", post a picture

Answer (score 2):

If you can't maintain 1/4" per foot (2 cm/m) slope on the drain pipe, you need to:

- choose a different sink
- choose a different disposal with an output that is higher relative
  to the current disposal
- choose not to have a disposal
- or lower the point where the pipe is entering the wall, so that you
  can maintain the required drain slope.

Yes, the last option is a pain. But it can be done.

You'll have problems with the drain if it's level or running uphill to get to the wall pipe, particularly with a disposal dumping material in that will settle out and build up in the section without proper slope.

Comment: or raise the counter (also a pain, but depending on how much and what stage of reno perhaps doable)